# Yoast XML Sitemaps and Docker WordPress not working

Tags: wordpress, docker, sitemap

I am using the official WordPress image with Apache and can confirm that the htaccess file in the container is being used because I can cause an Server Errror with incorrect code.

All seems well apart from the Yoast SEO plugin - the XML sitemap just will not show up as expected.

I have read this official help page and checked it all...

https://yoast.com/help/xml-sitemaps-apache/

...but it does not work for me.

Here is an extract of the Docker Compose file which shows the volume mount...

```
  domain.co.uk-wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - domain.co.uk-wordpress_db
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: domain.co.uk-wordpress
    restart: always
    networks:
      nginx-proxy-manager:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.30
    volumes:
      - ./data/html:/var/www/html
```

Here is the content of the .htaccess file...

```
# Yoast SEO - XML Sitemap Rewrite Fix
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap_index.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^locations.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml [L]
RewriteRule ^geo_sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=geo [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?-?sitemap.xsl$ /index.php?yoast-sitemap-xsl=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END Yoast SEO - XML Sitemap Rewrite Fix

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

...but the SEO Sitemap part is ignored.

Can anyone help to get this working or is this a known limitation of Docker WordPress?

Thanks!

Paully

Comment: What does "will not show up as expected" mean?  Is there an error?  Is the sitemap blank?

Comment: The sitemap does not show and the site shows the standard 404 error page. The Docker image Apache error log is linked to error.log -> /dev/stderr . Here is an extract from the log file - - [07/Apr/2022:10:01:32 +0100] "GET /sitemap_index.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 20134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0". So, it errors but I cannot debug it :-(

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: If you hit `/index.php?sitemap=1 ` is it also a 404 error?